# Proof of ratio test for complex series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I know it's proof for real numbers, and I can prove that if a complex series converges absolutely, it converges. Thus I indirectly proves that for $L < 1$, the series converges absolutely, so it converges. But for cases of $L = 1$, or $L > 1$, I can't say that it converges absolutely. In cases of $L = 1$, but it converges absolutely, of course it converges.
But I am not able to prove that for $L > 1$, it diverges.

Comment: What is $L$? Please give more context!

Comment: L is the ratio of the modulus of an+1/an as n tends to infinity.